# Recursive animation in jQuery is not working

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I've created a function to scroll several images horizontally in a header of my website. So inside of my header I have code similar to this:

```
<div class='images'> <!-- this div is 150% wide with overflow hidden -->
     <img src=... /><img src=... /><img src=... /><img src=... />
</div>
```

It is supposed to work like that:

1. Get the first image, using animation scroll it outside of the field of view to the left (using it's `margin-left` property)
2. Move the first image to the end (in fact it removes the image and creates a new one at the end).
3. Restart the whole process.

I've created following function:

```
function scroll()
{
    var o = jQuery('.images').children().first();
    var w = o.css('width');
    var s = o.attr('src');
    jQuery('.images:first-child').animate({'margin-left': "-"+w}, {'duration': 1000, 'complete': function(){
        jQuery('.images').children().first().remove();
        jQuery('.images').append("<img src='"+s+"' />");
        scroll();}});
}
```

Right now it works in following way: The first image is animated properly, then all next images are not scrolled (the animation does not work), but after the time of `1000` ms the first image is being moved to the end. So in fact the images are changing, but the animation is not working.

I suppose that the `scroll()` function at the end is called too early, but how to chain it properly?

Comment: Just to point out this part "jQuery('.images:first-child')" you are not targeting the images, but the holder itself. Or you have multiply images holder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if I'm not mistaken this is what you want to do:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86pmt/)

The only difference that you missed to target the images itsef.

```
 jQuery('.images img:first-child')
```